# Base class with virtual method and only implementing a guard clause

Tags: c#, oop

If you have a base class defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseMessageObject<T> where T : Entity
{        
  public string Message { get; set; }        
  public abstract BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity);
}
```

and you have a base class for HTMLObjectMessages defined as follows:

```
public abstract class HtmlMessageObject<T> : BaseMessageObject<T> 
   where T : Entity
{
  public override abstract BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity);
}
```

and you have a concrete implementation of the HtmlMessage as follows:

```
public class SocialSecurityVerificationHtmlMessageObject<T>:HtmlMessageObject<T>
   where T : SomeConcreteEntity
{
   public override BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity)
   {
      SocialSecurityVerificationHtmlMessageObject<T> message = 
            new SocialSecurityVerificationHtmlMessageObject<T>();            
      //do some stuff to build the message
   }
}
```

Is there any harm in placing guard clauses in the base MessageObject as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseMessageObject<T> where T : Entity
{        
   public string Message { get; set; }        
   public virtual BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity)
   {
      if (null == entity)
               throw new ArgumentNullException(entity)
      throw new NotImplemenetedException("");
   }
}
```

Something about this feels wrong.  Should this be refactored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseMessageObject<T> where T : Entity
{        
   public string Message { get; set; }        

   public BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity)
   {
        if (null == entity)
               throw new ArgumentNullException(entity)
        BuildMessageCore (entity);
   }

   protected abstract BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessageCore(T entity);
}
```

Comment: +1: seems to be a fair use of the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SocialSecurityVerificationHtmlMessageObject<T> : HtmlMessageObject<T>
    where T : SomeConcreteEntity
```

is conflict with base which is

```
public abstract class BaseMessageObject<T>  
    where T : Entity
```

different where T . u can't declare 2 different type parameter inherited line

u can do this

```
public class SocialSecurityVerificationHtmlMessageObject<T> : HtmlMessageObject<SomeConcreteEntity> 
    where T : SomeConcreteEntity
```

but the problem is your base class will never know what T really is.

Comment: Wrong. There is no conflict if `SomeConcreteEntity` inherits from `Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [code contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236408.aspx):

```
[ContractClass(typeof(BaseMessageObjectContract<>))]
public abstract class BaseMessageObject<T> where T : Entity {         
  public string Message { get; set; }         
  public abstract BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity); 
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(BaseMessageObject<>))]
abstract class BaseMessageObjectContract<T> : BaseMessageObject<T> 
  where T : Entity {
  public override BaseMessageObject<T> BuildMessage(T entity) { 
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(entity != null);
    return null;
  }
}
```

You should also [enable runtime checking](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/04/using-runtime-checking-of-code-contracts-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) of your preconditions.